# Suche ein griffiges Antonym zu chic/schick

Tags: single-word-request, antonym

Wenn jemand gut und geschmackvoll, gerne auch elegant und modisch gekleidet ist, spricht man von einer [*schicken*](https://www.dwds.de/wb/chic) Kleidung, oder heute zunehmend auch von einem *schicken Outfit*.

Was wäre nun aber das Gegenteil? Also, wenn jemand keinen Wert auf gute Kleidung legt und dementsprechend gleichgültig gekleidet ist.

Mir fällt außer dem umgangssprachlichen Ausruck *schlumpfig* wenig ein. *Altmodisch/unmodern* wäre das Antonym zu *modisch/moden*, *ungepflegt* passt gar nicht.

Zwar ginge *unschick* (so wie *unelegant*), aber das ist natürlich so trivial wie *nicht schick*. Hat jemand eine bessere Idee?

Comment: Das ist schwierig - Das Gegenteil von "besonders schick gekleidet" ist eben "nicht besonders schick gekleidet" und kann von "ranzig" bis "unelegant" und sogar "normal" alles sein.

Comment: @tofro: ich bin beruhigt, dass es nicht nur mir so geht :)

Comment: Das was du selbst geschrieben hast: "gleichgültig gekleidet"

Comment: "Nachlässig gekleidet" ist auch eine Möglichkeit.

Comment: Ich bestreite schon deinen zweiten Absatz: "nicht schick" heißt nicht automatisch "legt keinen Wert auf gute Kleidung und ist dementsprechend gleichgültig gekleidet". Das trifft zum Beispiel nicht auf den Handwerker mit der Latzhose zu.

Comment: @tofro Natürlich nicht. So wie *du* geschrieben hast: das Gegenteil hat eine weite Spannbreite von verlottert, abgerissen bis eben "normal".

Comment: Es gibt ja sogar den *lässigen Chic*.

Comment: @RHa "Nachlässig" unterstellt schon ein "Motiv" - "schick" nicht.

Comment: "stillos" und "unansehnlich" fallen mir noch ein

Comment: Sind *elegant* und *modisch* nicht bereits Gegensätze? Das Gegenteil zu *modisch* ist jedenfalls *zeitlos*.

Answer (score 4):

Wie wär's mit altbacken, hausbacken, bieder oder reizlos?

Answer (score 2):

Als Antonym zu 'schick' - abgesehen von den Möglichkeiten, die du in der Frage schon aufzählst (unschick, schlumpfig...) - wie wär's mit

> achtlos gekleidet
>
> mit unauffälliger Kleidung / unauffällig gekleidet
>
> in Alltagskleidung / Alltagskleidern
>
> unprätentiös gekleidet
>
> in schlichter Kleidung / schlicht gekleidet
>
> in normalen Klamotten
>
> einfach gekleidet

Als Variation zu *schlumpfig* kenne ich noch

> schluffig

In eine andere Richtung - nämlich in die von Tofro mit *ranzig* markierte - gehen

> schlampig gekleidet
>
> nachlässig gekleidet
>
> abgerissen herumlaufen
>
> verratzt

Zeichnete man eine Skala, dann wäre *schick* z.B. bei plus 10, *in Alltagskleidung* bei Null, und *verratzt* bei minus zehn.

Eine andere Konnotation hätte

> in einem peinlichen Outfit

(wobei man statt 'Outfit' vielleicht auch altmodischer 'Aufzug' sagen könnte). Während *schlampig gekleidet* meint, dass die Person einfach nicht auf das Aussehen der Kleidung achtet (obwohl sie vielleicht könnte), weist *in peinlichem Outfit* darauf hin, dass die Person trotz erheblichen Bemühens, schick zu erscheinen, dies nicht erreicht hat.

Ähnlich sind

> aufgedonnert
>
> aufgebretzelt

welche jedoch dazu tendieren, auch Make-up und Haartracht in die Bewertung einzubeziehen.

Comment: Siehe meinen Kommentar oben: "schick" konzentriert sich auf das Äußere, während "nachlässig" oder "achtlos" sowohl das Äußere als auch die Motivation addressiert.

Comment: Ja... man kann sicherlich auch unterscheiden zwischen "unabsichtlich unschick" und "absichtlich unschick". Wie man natürlich sowohl absichtlich als auch unabsichtlich schick sein kann.

Comment: Je länger ich mir das ansehe, desto mehr gefällt mir *schlicht* :)